# Оправдано ли применение !important при использовании отдельного класса для :hover

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Пишу на `scss`. Для `hover` эффектов выделил отдельный класс `.is-hovered:hover`. При добавлении класса к кнопке, например, должен меняться фон.

И есть стили, которые в css компилируются по такому пути `#l-main > .caption .button`, и если к ним просто дописать класс `is-hovered` в `html`, то эффекта не будет, так как, как я понял, стили переписываются.

Собственно вопрос, стоит ли написать в классе `.is-hovered:hover {background: #fff!important}`?

Answer (score 2):

Использование `!important` **настоятельно не рекомендую**. В последствии, такой код очень трудно поддерживать. Используется `!important` в случаях, когда другого выхода нет. Наследовании CSS стилей, довольно интересная штука, поэтому следует быть внимательным.

Судя из описания(если я правильно понимаю задачу) код должен выглядеть примерно так:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="l-main">
    <div class="caption">
        <button class="button">
            Some Button
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <button class="button is-hovered">
            Some Button hovered
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption">
                <button class="button is-hovered">
                    Some Button hovered
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="label is-hovered">
    Some label hovered
</div>
<div class="label">
    Some label
</div>

<div class="some-class is-hovered">
    Some class hovered
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
@mixin is-hovered {
    &.is-hovered {
        &:hover {            
            background-color: green; 
        }
    }
}

#l-main {
    margin-top: 10px;

    &>.caption {
        border: 1px dashed red;
        margin: 5px 0;

        .button {            
            border: 0;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background-color: orange;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;

            @include is-hovered;
        }
    }
}

.label {
    color: white;    
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;

    @include is-hovered;
}

.some-class {
    @include is-hovered;
}
```

Класс `is-hovered` можно обернуть в миксин и добавлять ко всем классам, где он нужен. Но вложенность нужно соблюдать в любом случае. Если вы будете использовать `!important`, то в будущем перекрыть свойства с ним в классе `is-hovered` будет уже достаточно трудно. Например: `is-hovered active`; или переопределить его в будущем для конкретного элемента.

Напоследок: перед тем как принимать решение с использованием `!important`, хорошо подумайте, какие могут быть последствия его применения в будущем.

Пример на jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n2kp0cp4/2/

Comment: Почти правлиьно поняли. Фишка только в том, что класс .is-hovered описан отдельно от всего. И этот класс будет с помощью js добавляться к элементу в html. Я так понимаю это делется для того, что бы не прописывать , как у вас в примере, ховер для 100 ссылок в разных частях сайта. Поправите если я не прав